# CSS and Javascript optimization (Speed issue)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, optimization

So I am trying to make a wheel navigation system in css and javascript using Angular. It is working perfectly fine but I am wondering if there is a better way to optimize it for less load, it works great on new devices but pretty slow on older ones. Currently on drag (using hammer js, so this is happening 60 times per second) I am running this code.

```
        var pageX = e.gesture.center.pageX;
        var pageY = e.gesture.center.pageY;
        currentAngle = getAngle(pageX, pageY) - updatedAngle + originalAngle;
        absoluteAngle = getAngle(pageX, pageY);
        circle.style.transform = circle.style.webkitTransform  = 'rotateZ(' + currentAngle + 'deg)';
        for (var i = 0; i < circles.length; i++) {
          circles[i].style.transform = circles[i].style.webkitTransform = 'rotateZ(' + -currentAngle + 'deg)';
        }
```

Where updatedAngle and originalAngle are variables set on start, and getAngle is this function

```
    var getAngle = function(x, y){
      var deltaX = x - center.x,
          deltaY = y - center.y,
          angle = Math.atan2(deltaY, deltaX) * 180 / Math.PI;
      if(angle < 0) {
        angle = angle + 360;
      }
      return angle;
    };
```

There are usually 12-15 sections or (circles) so I can see how this is going slow, a for loop that runs ~15 times, inside of an event that happens 60 times a second. The first rotate is the movement of the parent div that moves the objects, and the loop adjusts their rotation so they are upright. Should I try frame skipping? and make the event happen less? Is there a way I could batch the css changes? Is there something better than rotateZ? (I tried rotate() and it was about 10% slower). Any ideas would help

Comment: Do you have an example? maybe a fiddle?

Comment: Optimisation questions aren't really suited to Stack Overflow. Perhaps [**CodeReview**](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) **BUT** check their [**guidelines**](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour) ***first***.

Comment: One of the fastest in browser animating methods is pure css - I highly trying to add an easing to your circle elements in css and when you want to rotate them, do it all at once instead of rotating it each degree (the easing will do the work)

Comment: There are multiple micro optimizations you can do, but i dont know if that will help much.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying a freestyle coding micro-optimization-answer. Haven't tested it but I hope you get the essence.

In the first function it was possible to remove a few variables since they were duplicates. Multiple variable declarations could make it slow in older browsers.

```
var absoluteAngle = getAngle(e.gesture.center.pageX, e.gesture.center.pageY);
currentAngle = angle - updatedAngle + originalAngle;
circle.style.transform = circle.style.webkitTransform  = 'rotateZ(' + currentAngle + 'deg)';
for (var i = 0; i < circles.length; i++) {
    circles[i].style.transform = circles[i].style.webkitTransform = 'rotateZ(' + -currentAngle + 'deg)';
}
```

In this function, there was not much optimization that could be done. But same here, you can remove the variables and save a few ticks.

```
var getAngle = function(x, y){
    var angle = Math.atan2(y - center.y, x - center.x) * 180 / Math.PI;
    if(angle < 0) {
        angle = angle + 360;
    }

    return angle;
};
```

Not much, but without a plunker or something its a bit hard to optimize.